# Shadowing parts of a dynamic variable

Tags: common-lisp, dynamic-binding

Maybe I'm trying to be too creative here.

Is it possible to extend the concept of dynamic binding to `SETF`able *places* of a dynamic variable, so that I can shadow *part of* a dynamic variable (such as a plist) with `LET` bindings?

For example, I would like to be able to do something like:

```
(defparameter *foo* '(:one 1))

(let (((getf *foo* :one) 2))
  (do-things))
```

To shadow the value of :one with 2.

This example doesn't work since `(getf *foo* :one)` is not a variable name that `LET` can assign a value to, but perhaps there is another way?

Comment: In the case of plists and alists, you can shadow the previous bindings instead of modifying the underlying list (which could be problematic with concurrent/reentrant code): `(let ((*foo* (list* :one 2 *foo*))) ...)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no standard way, but some implementations may offer
extensions, e.g., [`letf`](https://clisp.sourceforge.io/impnotes/macros3.html#letf).

Alternatively, you can use
[`unwind-protect`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_unwind.htm) yourself:

```
(let ((old-value (getf *foo* :one)))
  (unwind-protect
       (progn (setf (getf *foo* :one) 2)
              (do-things))
    (setf (getf *foo* :one) old-value)))
```

If this is a common operation in your code, you might even define a macro for that:

```
(defmacro with-one (tmp-one &body body)
  "Bind (getf *foo* :one) to tmp-one around body."
  (let ((old-value (gensym "WITH-ONE-OLD")))
    `(let ((,old-value (getf *foo* :one)))
       (unwind-protect
            (progn (setf (getf *foo* :one) ,tmp-one)
                   ,@body)
         (setf (getf *foo* :one) ,old-value)))))
```